# Property expressions for nested classes JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a class `CompanyMember` which has one-to-one mapping with `Department` and `Designation` class both of which have property `id` which represent there respective department and designation id.

I am trying to use **Spring Data JPA** to get them, this is the method I have invoked

```
Page<CompanyMember> findAllByDesignation_idAndDepartment_id
                       (Long Department_id,Long Designation_id, Pageable pageable);
```

for some reason it's sending me null value in result no error only null result, I have checked the database that is why I am sure it should not send null result.

Can anyone point out where it went wrong?

Comment: You're trying to use __Spring Data JPA__ to get them; this is not the JPA API, it is a layer on top of it.

Comment: It looks okay, could you provide example of the repository definition and how you use this method?